# Struct cross module initializers

Tags: ios, swift, struct, module, initialization

I have been working on a project which has some different modules.
In First Module:

I have somthing like this

```
public struct User: Codable {
    // MARK: Stored Properties
    public let id: String
    public let name: String
    public let email: String
}

extension User {
    public enum FetchProfile { }
}

extension User.FetchProfile {
    public struct Input {
        public let userId: String
    }

    public struct Output {
        public var user: User
    }
}
```

And in the other module:

```
import FirstModule

extension User.FetchProfile.Output {

    init(object: JSON) throws {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let jsonData = Data(value.description.utf8)
        self.user = try! decoder.decode(User.self, from: jsonData)
    }
}
```

if i use swift 5 i got this error:

> 'self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self'
>
> 'self.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from
> initializer

but in swift 4 i have this warning:

> Initializer for struct 'User.FetchProfile.Output' must use
> "self.init(...)" or "self = ..." because it is not in module
> 'SecondModule'

I already read what in this link:
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0189-restrict-cross-module-struct-initializers.md

But I'm still did not get it, what should i do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
extension User.FetchProfile {
    public struct Input {
        public let userId: String
    }

    public struct Output {
        public var user: User? = nil    // << here !!
    }
}
```

and in second module

```
extension User.FetchProfile.Output {

    init(object: JSON) throws {
        self.init()               // << here !!

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let jsonData = Data(value.description.utf8)
        self.user = try? decoder.decode(User.self, from: jsonData)
    }
}
```

Comment: He give me this error when calling self.init():
Missing argument for parameter 'object' in call